# How do I receive email sent to postmaster?

Tags: ssl-certificate, sendmail, verification

I have a VPS server that I would like to get an SSL certificate for, and the CA needs an email address to verify that I own the domain.  The options are: `postermaster@mydomain.com`, `hostmaster@mydomain.com`, `webmaster@mydomain.com`, and an address to `@whoisguard.com`.

The server runs CentOS 5, and all I have set up for email is `sendmail`.  I don't have POP3 or IMAP.  According to [this Wikipedia article on Postmaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmaster_(computing)), it says that all SMTP servers support postmaster and it cites RFC 5321.  Does `sendmail` conform to this?  I tried sending a test mail to `postermaster@mydomain.com`, but I don't know how to receive it on my server.  Do I need to open up any ports?

I haven't gotten a message back saying that my test mail failed to send, so my server must have gotten it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `/etc/aliases`.  Usually, `postmaster` is redirected to `root`; the question becomes who gets `root`'s mail  Best practice is to add an alias to route it to your email address (e.g. `root: me@gmail.com`), then `sudo newaliases` to install the new alias file.

Comment: I tried this.  I checked `/var/mail/root`, and my Gmail account; I sent 4 or 5 emails, and I haven't gotten any of them.  Do I need to setup any permissions to receive mail?  `/etc/mail/access` for instance?

Comment: Possibly, but first you need to know what's happening to the mail.  Check `/var/log/mail` for error messages, and run `mailq` to see if the messages are "stuck" for some reason and why.

Comment: The mail log only has stuff from when I ran `newaliases`.  `mailq` says the queue is empty.

Comment: I think the problem is that I can't access port 25.  I shut down iptables, and nmap says port 25 is filtered which probably means my VPS provider is blocking it.